# Adding a required in a basic for of an input and button

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I tried to add a required element (when the box become red if not text is inside) on my form but without success, I installed react-strap, Bootstrap. when I apply many changed it didn't work for no reason
and it's just not moving if someone know why I would be happy.

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
      <InputGroup size="sm">
        <InputGroupAddon addonType="append" className="m-2">
          <Input
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Add a new To-Do. "
            onChange={(e) => this.updateInput(e.target.value)}
            value={this.state.input}
            onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
            required
          />
          <Button
            color="primary"
            size="sm"
            className="add-todo"
            onClick={this.handleAddTodo}
          >
            Add
          </Button>
        </InputGroupAddon>
      </InputGroup>
    </form>
  </div>
);
}

export default connect(null, { addTodo })(AddTodo);
// export default AddTodo;
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with bootstrap. Have you used `required = true`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is passing `required` as a prop to your class `Input`.  You need to add the html tag when the field renders, i.e. in `Input.js`:

```
return (
    <input ... required={this.props.required}>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add the **'is-invalid'** class to the input element if that field is empty.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/?#server-side